# How to rotate div content in email template

Tags: html-email

In a email template I want to rotate a div content by `90deg`.

I tried property `transform: rotate(90deg)` but it is not working in email template. I know the `transform property` not supporting in email template.

Is there another way or any trick to rotate content in email template?

**Edit** : I want to to rotate below div content :

```
...
<td>
   <div><p>Some content <br> Some content</p></div>
</td>
...
```

Comment: CSS support in email is really tricky/incomplete, you should rotate your content "by hand" and have the rotated content directly in your HTML, without further modifications.

Comment: What is it that you want to rotate? Is it a img or a text or what? And do you want to rotate it permanently or bulid interactive content? Please provide some more code

Comment: Hello @Niklas Felt, Please check my edited question.

Comment: No you can't rotate a div in an email template.

Comment: Hello @Joshua Duxbury, I want to rotate `Some content` in email template so enclose in a div, Is it possible to rotate text?

Comment: @VinayaMaheshwari I would test the transform property on the div, the td and the p. Each inline and in style tag and maybe you can get anything to work somewhere. CSS animation work in some clients like Applemail, an there I use transform a lot. So it should be possible for at least some clients

Comment: I tried property on `div` `p` `span` tag but not working and I want to rotate in `gmail` for now.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, as you note, support for CSS `transform` [is not good in email clients](http://freshinbox.com/resources/css.php).

[image]

If the design lends itself well with the text being rotated in some email clients and not others, use CSS `transform` on the `<div>` or `<p>`. It's clean and easy to use live text.

If the text *needs* to be rotated everywhere, the best bet is to **make the text an image**. Not ideal or scaleable, but it's reliable everywhere. You can use a tool like [Nifty Images](https://niftyimages.com/) if there are a lot of instances or versions of the text.